# How to use Sequential to without weight sharing in Layers Library?

Tags: cntk

I really like the sequential notation as it keeps my code compact. I notice in [the documentation](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/layerref.html#sequential) it reads that sequential promotes weight sharing so in the following code block all the parameters are shared:

```
lay = Sequential ([F, G, H])
y = lay (x)
z = lay (x)
```

How do I use Sequential in a way that creates two different instances but still allows for model description reuse? So y and z have their own weights, but I only have written Sequential in the code once? (Trying to keep my code compact)

Answer (score 1):

I've got two recommendations offline from Frank Seide.

Approach one is use CloneMethod in cntk.ops

```
lay = Sequential ([F, G, H])
lay2 = lay.clone(CloneMethod.clone) (x)
y = lay (x)
z = lay2 (x)
```

Another approach is to use a function outside

```
def createLayer():
    return Sequential ([F, G, H])

lay = createLayer()
lay2 = createLayer()
y = lay (x)
z = lay2 (x)
```

If you want to do everything on one line you can also do something like this

```
createLayer = lambda : Sequential([Embedding,Recurrence(LSTM(100)),sequence.last))
y = createLayer() (x)
z = createLayer() (x)
```